# login (php) with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, sql

I am trying to add a login scroll-down window in my page. The window itself works fine (http://pasionesargentas.webatu.com/test4.php), but now I need some help- I need an approach as to how to integrate the new input form to my actual log in system. In the scroll-down window you see the two fields (username and password) and the submit button. But the actual login system I have a totally new window (http://pasionesargentas.webatu.com/signin.php) where I do the whole checking and session start. I could probably merge the php login code with the scroll-down window, but I would not prefer to do that since that scroll-down window is in the header and I wouldn't like to run the check every single time a page (with the header) is opened. 
I am really afraid of not being understood so here I am adding some more lines of the same:

I have a javascript scroll down window with two fields (u/n and pass) and a submit button but I don't know how to check those values with the database so I can start the session for that user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use AJAX. I'll just write my code using the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/), as that is what I am familiar with.

When you press the Submit button on your login form, the browser sends a **POST** request to your login PHP page, which processes the request and sets up a session for the user.

You can emulate this behavior with JavaScript:

```
$.post('login.php', $('#id_of_login_form').serialize(), function(data) {
  alert('You have been logged in!');
});
```

This code will log you into your website from a different page.

Comment: thanks, Mr Blender. I changed the form action to login.php and for some reason it worked. I don't really know why since the login.php IS a form, but it validates it right. Sorry but I'm still kind of dumb with object oriented languages. THANKS

Comment: That works too (a better solution than mine, IMO). Either way the browser sends the POST to the `login.php` page.